# How to add Views on AVCaptureSession ?, like i have avcapturesession running but i cannot add a TextView below it

Tags: swiftui, avcapturesession

I am new to SwiftUI, and I was trying to building a app which recognizes objects using Resnet50 model and displays its recognized name, I was able to run the avcapturesession and print the objects name in console but i cant see the TextView when app is running, it always shows the camera fullScreen

This is my Content View

```
import SwiftUI
import AVKit
import Vision
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var cameraInfo = CameraViewController()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            CameraView()
            Text(cameraInfo.objectIdentifier)
        }
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
    }
}
```

And this is my CameraView which is UIViewControllerRepresentable

```
struct CameraView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> CameraViewController {
        return CameraViewController()
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: CameraViewController, context: Context) {
        print("Update Called")
    }
    
    typealias UIViewControllerType = CameraViewController
}
```

This is the CameraViewController

```
final class CameraViewController: UIViewController, ObservableObject,AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {
    var captureSession: AVCaptureSession!
   @Published var objectIdentifier: String = ""
    func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        guard let pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) else { return }
        guard let model = try? VNCoreMLModel(for: Resnet50().model) else { return }
        let request = VNCoreMLRequest(model: model) { (finishedRequest, error) in
            guard let results = finishedRequest.results as? [VNClassificationObservation] else { return }
            guard let firstObservation = results.first else { return }
            self.objectIdentifier = firstObservation.identifier
            print("DEBUG: firstObs identifier\(firstObservation.identifier),confidence\(firstObservation.confidence)")
        }
        try? VNImageRequestHandler(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer, options: [:]).perform([request])
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
        captureSession.sessionPreset = .photo
        guard let videoCaptureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video) else { return }
        guard let input = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: videoCaptureDevice) else {return}
        captureSession.addInput(input)
        captureSession.startRunning()
        let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
        previewLayer.frame = view.frame
        let dataOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
        dataOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue(label: "video"))
        captureSession.addOutput(dataOutput)
        
    }
}
```